# Error: Cannot find file [Content_Types].xml in zip

Tags: xlsx, angular9

I'm trying to upload the excel file and reading it on the file change but it's throwing the below error,

```
Error: Cannot find file [Content_Types].xml in zip
```

It seems `xlsx@0.16.0` is NOT working with `Angular 9`. Any help will be much appreciated.

Please checkout the snip here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqvflc

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. You're right, xlsx@0.16.0 doesn't seem to be working on Angular9.
I am also using stackblitz.
I fixed it by just installing the older version xlsx@0.14.2

Comment: Same situation.
The exact version helped me a lot; thank you!